# how to randomized the positions of images in imageViews

Tags: android, random, imageview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int [] layouts = {
        R.id.imageView1,
        R.id.imageView2,
        R.id.imageView3,
        R.id.imageView4,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int i = layouts.length;
            Random r = new Random();



            while (--i > 0) {

                int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);

                //swap values
                int temp = layouts[j];
                layouts[j] = layouts[i];
                layouts[i] = temp;


            }

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(layouts[i]);
            iv.setImageResource(layouts[i]);

            }


    });


}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

i have these 4 image Views. all i want is when i press the button their positions will randomly change  .ex. 1,2,3,4 becomes 2,3,1,4 or 4,3,2,1 something like that. when i try to run my code, the images simply disappearing 1 by 1. when i run it the 4 images becomes 3 and when i press the button its becomes 2 and so on until they all vanish. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need two arrays.

One containing ImageView Ids:

```
private int [] layouts = {
        R.id.imageView1,
        R.id.imageView2,
        R.id.imageView3,
        R.id.imageView4,
};
```

another containing image drawables:

```
private int [] drawables = {
        R.drawable.your_image1,
        R.drawable.your_image2,
        R.drawable.your_image3,
        R.drawable.your_image4,
};
```

Swap values of layouts array as you do (assuming your algorithm works).

Then assign each array item of drawable to each ImageView from layouts array:

```
ImageView iv;
for(i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++){
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(layouts[i]);
    iv.setImageResource(drawables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted